# Network bootstrapper could not generate node info files

Tags: corda

I followed below instruction in the documentation:
https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html#bootstrapping-a-test-network

And I have below structure of the node info root folder
[image: Original Structure]

Then I run below command:

`java -jar corda-network-bootstrapper-3.2-corda-executable.jar --dir C:\Project\Blockchain\bootstrapper`

But in the command window below error was shown:

```
Bootstrapping local network in C:\Project\Blockchain\bootstrapper\--dir
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No nodes found
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper.bootstrap(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:73)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.main(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:64)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper.main(NetworkBootstrapper.kt)
```

Comment: I found the root cause is we should not add --dir in the command, replace it with the diretory name directly. But not sure whether this is one needed update for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For 3.2 I did the following instead and it worked:
java -jar corda-network-bootstrapper-3.2-corda-executable.jar

Comment: I get the below error -

C:\Corda\test_network\sample>java -jar c:\Corda\tools\corda-network-bootstrapper-3.2-corda-executable.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting first argument which is the nodes' parent directory

Answer (score 0):

The below worked -

java -jar c:\Corda\tools\corda-network-bootstrapper-3.2-corda-executable.jar C:\Corda\test_network\sample\

In C:\Corda\test_network\sample\, I had 3 node conf files and this generated all the required nodes and the bootstrapping completed with the message -

Bootstrapping complete!